# Connecting QGIS to Esri Enterprise Geodatabase of type Oracle Spatial

Tags: qgis, enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-spatial, connection

I have an Esri Enterprise Geodatabase (ArcSDE 10.2.2; Oracle 10G).

I am trying to connect it with QGIS 2.16.

So I clicked "`Add vector layer`" button with "Database" 
Type : Oracle Spatial (I've tried with "ESRI Personal GeDatabase)
I filled the parameters of the connection.

I clicked "`Test`" button -> connection successful

When I click OK I've got this message :

> Invalid Data Source: OCI:admin/admin@dbpsigdat.nimes.fr:1522/psigdat
>   is not a valid or recognized data source

Can anybody help me ?

Comment: Try  Add Layer >Oracle Spatial rather than vector layer database they use different drivers to retrieve the data

Comment: Thanks for your response. When I use "Oracle Spatial Layer", I've some system tables appatenant au USER MDSYS, even if i'm not connected with. Layers are for exemple :
ALL_SDO_INDEX_METADATA
ALL_SDO_STYLES
CS_SRS
DBA_SDO_STYLES
etc. I use ST_GEOMETRY and not SDO_GEOMETRY.
Could it be a reason ?

Comment: This is not an answer.  Please edit your question and move this information there and delete this answer.

Comment: tick the 'only look in user's table' for your tables on the create A New Oracle connection'

Answer (score 1):

The is comment with an image
[image]

To get to your own tables using QGIS and the Oracle Spatial Tables use these settings

Comment: So i didn't see any table of my user.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to stock data in SDO_GEOMETRY and no ST_GEOMETRY.

[ST_GEOMETRY to SDO_GEOMETRY](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/187686/st-geometry-to-sdo-geometry)

Bad news for me.