# How to find nearest neighbor in Oracle's ST_GEOMETRY?

Tags: oracle-spatial, nearest-neighbor, st-geometry, sdo-geometry

I am trying to find nearest road segment to a point in Oracle. I can do this with *SDO_GEOMETRY* type i.e

```
select 
/*+ LEADING(pois) INDEX(route ALL_ROUTES_SPTAIL_INDEX)  */  
route.*
from DEVICE_STATUS pois,ALL_ROUTES route where 
MDSYS.sdo_nn(route.shape, pois.shape,'sdo_num_res=1') = 'TRUE'
and pois.objectid=729415
```

How can I find nearest neighbor when both tables have *ST_GEOMETRY* type? or is there any way to convert 
*ST_GEOMETRY* to *SDO_GEOMETRY*

Comment: You accepted Asad's answer so I will guess he answered what you thought you were asking.  However, I would read your question to be asking how to find the nearest neighbors for "Oracle's ST_GEOMETRY", e.g. MDSYS.ST_GEOMETRY.  Asad is talking about "Esri's ST_GEOMETRY" or SDE.ST_GEOMETRY. They are two utterly different items from two different vendors.

I am just putting this comment here for anyone else coming along with the docs link:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/spatl/sql-multimedia-type-support.html#GUID-22FE0E11-C9F0-4E1A-B512-D494E588FFAA

Comment: @pauldzy, since there isn't any way to find nearest neighbor from st_geometry. Therefore, only option I am left with is to convert ST_GEOMETRY(Oracle's or Esri's, does not matter here) to sdo_geometry first and then find the neighbors.

Comment: The term "ST_GEOMETRY" is overloaded in the Oracle context, because there is a native type with that name. You should specify SDE.ST_GEOMETRY where you mean the Esri type and MDSYS.ST_GEOMETRY where you reference the native Oracle type. The alternative is to explicitly call out the vendor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you will need to convert st_geom to wkt and then create sdo_geom from wkt, something like this should work.

```
select SDO_UTIL.FROM_WKTGEOMETRY(sde.st_astext(shape),SRID) from table;
```

you can also refer to [this](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SPATL/sdo_util-from_wktgeometry.htm#SPATL1234) or you can also try

```
select sdo_geometry(sde.st_astext(shape),SRID) from table;
```

as described [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/187686/st-geometry-to-sdo-geometry)

Comment: The thing that makes nearest-neighbor work is the ability to leverage the spatial index. Casting between types will *not* utilize a spatial index, and therefore not perform adequately for tables of any significance. You need a "second" (or more) to pair with your "first".